# logs inside django channels consumers not showing up

Tags: python, django, django-channels

Environment:

```
OS: redhat
python version: 3.6
django: 2.1
django channels: 2.1.3
```

The following is my logging.conf file (same level as settings.py):

```
LOGGING = {
'version': 1,
'disable_existing_loggers': False,
'formatters': {
    'standard': {
        'format': '%(asctime)s [%(levelname)s] %(name)s: %(message)s',
        'datefmt': '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S',
    },
},
'handlers': {
    'file': {
        'level': 'DEBUG',
        'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
        'filename': 'debug.log',
        'formatter': 'standard'
    },
},
'loggers': {
    'django': {
        'handlers': ['file'],
        'level': 'DEBUG',
        'propagate': True,
    },
},
}

django_logger = logging.getLogger('django')
```

and the function to log as follows:

```
def log_it(*args):
    try:
        django_logger.info(str(args).encode('utf-8'))
        return True
    except:
        django_logger.info('#### Exception in LOGGING!!!!!!')
    return False
```

I am using this to log inside django consumers as follows:

```
class EchoConsumer(SyncConsumer):
   def websocket_connect(self, event):
      try:
          log_it('inside EchoConsumer connect()', event)
          self.send({
            "type": "websocket.accept",
          })
        return True
      except:
          error = traceback.format_exc()
          write_error_log(error)
      return False

   def websocket_receive(self, event):
      try:
          log_it('inside EchoConsumer receive()', event)
          self.send({
            "type": "websocket.send",
            "text": event["text"],
          })
          return True
      except:
          error = traceback.format_exc()
          write_error_log(error)
      return False
```

**The log_it() used inside the consumers aren't being invoked**.

*(Assumption: Integrating channels with django must have overriden the django logging settings)*

I checked if there was any problem in reaching the consumers in the daphne access logs.
I also checked my nginx conf, but the connection requests were recorded as follows:

```
127.0.0.1:45100 - - [08/Oct/2018:19:00:58] "WSCONNECTING /ws/event/" - -
127.0.0.1:45100 - - [08/Oct/2018:19:00:58] "WSCONNECT /ws/event/" - -
```

> Note: I have linked /ws/event to EchoConsumer in routing.py

My expectation is:

```
127.0.0.1:45100 - - [08/Oct/2018:19:00:58] "WSCONNECTING /ws/event/" - -
127.0.0.1:45100 - - [08/Oct/2018:19:00:58] "WSCONNECT /ws/event/" - -
inside EchoConsumer connect() ....
```

Any idea why the log statements are not being displayed?

P.S [related issue on github](https://github.com/django/channels/issues/520)

Comment: Are you supposed to do something with `LOGGING` after defining it?  Are you supposed to pass any arguments to `basicConfig()`?

Comment: You say the first code sample is your `logging.conf` file, but it's python code.  Do you really have python code in a `.conf` file?  If so, how is it used?

Comment: yes, the logging is stored inside logging.conf file and follows the pattern as described in the docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/logging/

Comment: I don't see anywhere on that page that says to use a `logging.conf` file.  It does mention the `logging.config` _module_, but that's completely different...

Comment: logging.conf is just a file holding the django logging configuration in dictconfig format. The configuration inside LOGGING is merged with django default logging and configured using django's setup() as described in the docs. Also I have removed basicConfig() as it has no effect from the code.

Comment: Okay, I'll take your word for it.  Next issue, you've only configured a logger for the django module itself.  Log statements that are inside your application aren't covered by this logger.

Comment: That's why i have written the log_it() function. It logs to the django logger